# Controlling print jobs using CUPS API

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printing, cups

So I am using CUPS installed on a linux machine as a printer server in a local network.
The problems is that, before directly sending the Print job to the network printer, I want to impelement the **Hold-Job** operation.
I've actually searched in the CUPS APIS' function but without any result.
**So If you have any idea or hint that can help me just mention it please, note that I am using <cups/cups.h> library for programming**

Thank you in advance ^^.

Comment: To me it is not clear what you mean with "store it [the print job] in the server itself until authentication". Please [edit] your question and explain your use case in more detail, maybe adding an example of what you want to happen step by step. Showing your incomplete code might also help.

Comment: Your edit does not make the question much clearer. Maybe this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62741730/10622916 (I know this is Python while you might be using C.)